# How I can disable a button when clicked until the frame closed?

Tags: java, button, jframe, windowbuilder

I want to disable the button after it gets clicked one time until the frame is closed by the user then the button gets enabled again

I tried

```
  ((AbstractButton)evt.getSource).setEnabled(false);
```

but it makes the button usable for once only,

the problem is when I click the button x times, the CPU goes 99% and the frame is opened x times

the button takes a screenshot from a website, so it takes time to open the frame with the screenshot, so if a user clicked the button 10 times, the operation becomes slower and everything pops up together

Comment: Java Swing provides the concept of event listeners...register an action listener to the button, disable it after the button was clicked. done

Comment: but how it will be `enabled` again after the frame is closed ? (the button open a frame with a screenshot inside it)

Comment: or to make it easier, how i can disable it for x seconds ?

Comment: As I said, Java Swing provides event listeners for basically everything in the UI. And yes, also windows closing listeners, like `frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {` ...

Comment: @AKSW thank you so much, your solution worked, please post the answer so i can accepted it as the best answer